# Symbology based on field names and values in ArcMap 10.5

Tags: arcmap, symbology, arcgis-10.5

Is there a way to apply symbology based on field names as well as the values per each field?

I have a road layer where the fields are years and each road segment has an attribute value of 1 (had work done in that year) or 0 (no work done that year).I would like to apply symbology that shows road segments with attribute value of 1 in 2018 to be blue, 2017 to be red, 2016 to be green, etc. I have fields from 2000 to 2018 so more than the 3 fields that you can bring into the 'multiple attributes' symbology option.

I know how to pick all roads that had work done and apply a symbology to that but how do I also add in the further distinction of year?

Answer (score 3):

Look into the Symbology -> Multiple Attributes -> Quantity by category. there you can choose up to three fields it looks like, and each symbol would be a combination of them.

So if you input your years, 2016, 2017, 2018 for instance, each having values of 0 or 1. The resultant symbology would be 2016-0, 2016-1, 2017-0, and so on.

Comment: Thanks! I looked into that but looks like you can only add max 3 fields? I have 18 - will edit my question to include this. And I also don't care about symbology for the roads with attribute values of '0'. I just want 2016 -1, 2017-1, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Update: I made a separate layer for each year, applied desired symbology, and then grouped all the layers together.